# Alphanumeric text in select's option sorted by first part of the complex string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Probably, I have a stupid question, but how can I sort alphanumeric text in select's option?
Example:

```
  <select> <option>H123-128kbps</option>
           <option>H123-1024kbps</option>
           <option>H130-128kbps</option>
           <option>H123-512kbps</option>
           <option>H123-256kbps</option>
           <option>H130-256kbps</option>
  </select>
```

I would like to sort it like:

```
      <select><option>H123-128kbps</option>
              <option>H123-256kbps</option>
              <option>H123-512kbps</option>
              <option>H123-1024kbps</option>
              <option>H130-128kbps</option>                  
             <option>H130-256kbps</option>
        </select>
```

Currently, I receive partial results:

```
      <select><option>H123-128kbps</option>
              <option>H123-512kbps</option>
              <option>H123-1024kbps</option>
              <option>H123-256kbps</option>                  
              <option>H123-1024kbps</option>
              <option>H130-256kbps</option>
              <option>H130-128kbps</option>                
        </select>
```

This is my code :

```
            var options = $('select.whatever option'); 
            var arr = options.map(function (_, o) {
                return {t: $(o).text(), v: o.value};
            }).get();
            arr.sort(function (o1, o2) {
                return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
            });
            options.each(function (i, o) {
                o.value = arr[i].v;
                $(o).text(arr[i].t);
            });
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I tried to sort in a lot of different ways, like
                    var arr = options.map(function (_, o) {
                    return {t: $(o).text(), v: o.value};
                }).get();
                arr.sort(function (o1, o2) {
                    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
                });
                options.each(function (i, o) {
                    o.value = arr[i].v;
                    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
                });

but it's sort by the first part of my string:
H123 and fully ignore the second part  after "-"

Comment: I think you need to split the string compare the first and second (if the first part is the same)

Comment: And why do you have `td` on your js when you dont have `td` on your html?

Comment: I have it. Just don't want to post all html code here.

Comment: Edited my previous code